# illegal expression while using the 'if', 'while' and 'loop' method

Tags: java

I am trying to use 'If' and 'While' methods, along with 'loop' for this program where you can input number of grades and the program calculates an average of those grades and gives a letter value. The program worked fine when it was just calculating the average but when I tried using the if and while method to produce the letter grade - it started giving errors stating illegal expression for the clear and close method. Please help. I am pasting the main method. The error is pointed at the clear and close methods towards the very end.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         GradeCalculator application = new GradeCalculator();
         application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     }

        public void enterJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
          getAverageGrade();
     }

      public void getAverageGrade()
        {
            scoreAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Number of scores to be entered?:");
            numberOfScores = Integer.parseInt(scoreAmount);
            getFillupGrades();
        }

      public void getFillupGrades()
       {
         for(counter = 0; counter < numberOfScores; counter++)
       {
         scoreAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Score:");
         gradeValues = Integer.parseInt(scoreAmount);
         gradeAccumulator += gradeValues;
        }

        calculateAverage();
        }

        public void calculateAverage()
        {
            averageGrade = gradeAccumulator / numberOfScores;

        if (averageGrade > 89)
         {
           averageGradeJTextField.setText("A");

        if (averageGrade > 79)
         {
           averageGradeJTextField.setText("B");

       if (averageGrade > 69)
        {
         averageGradeJTextField.setText("C");

       if (averageGrade > 64)
        {
        averageGradeJTextField.setText("D");
        }
     else
       {
     averageGradeJTextField.setText("F");
        }

      public void clearJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
       {
        averageGradeJTextField.setText("");
       }

      public void closeJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
         GradeCalculator.this.dispose();
  }
  }
```

The error states:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g GradeCalculator.java

GradeCalculator.java:179: error: illegal start of expression
    public void clearJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    ^
GradeCalculator.java:179: error: illegal start of expression
    public void clearJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
           ^
GradeCalculator.java:179: error: ';' expected
    public void clearJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                                           ^
GradeCalculator.java:179: error: ';' expected
    public void clearJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                                                             ^
GradeCalculator.java:184: error: illegal start of expression
    public void closeJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    ^
GradeCalculator.java:184: error: illegal start of expression
    public void closeJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
           ^
GradeCalculator.java:184: error: ';' expected
    public void closeJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                                           ^
GradeCalculator.java:184: error: ';' expected
    public void closeJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                                                             ^
GradeCalculator.java:188: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
9 errors
```

Comment: You should start using indentation. A lot of problems will become more visible this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening a lot of `if` blocks, but you do not close them (code correctly indented):

```
public void calculateAverage() {
    averageGrade = gradeAccumulator / numberOfScores;
    if (averageGrade > 89) {
        averageGradeJTextField.setText("A");

        if (averageGrade > 79) {
            averageGradeJTextField.setText("B");

            if (averageGrade > 69) {
                averageGradeJTextField.setText("C");

                if (averageGrade > 64) {
                    averageGradeJTextField.setText("D");
                }
                else {
                    averageGradeJTextField.setText("F");
                }
```

Change that method as follows (included missing braces and used `else if` instead of `if`):

```
public void calculateAverage() {
    averageGrade = gradeAccumulator / numberOfScores;
    if (averageGrade > 89) {
        averageGradeJTextField.setText("A");
    } // was missing
    else if (averageGrade > 79) {
        averageGradeJTextField.setText("B");
    } // was missing
    else if (averageGrade > 69) {
        averageGradeJTextField.setText("C");
    } // was missing
    else if (averageGrade > 64) {
        averageGradeJTextField.setText("D");
    } // was missing
    else {
        averageGradeJTextField.setText("F");
    } // was missing
}
```

Comment: thank you Tom. I will make those edits- hopefully it will work.